# Jquery .off vs dojo?

Tags: dojo

What is equivalent of jquery `$.off(event)` to remove event on element by passing event name  in Dojo?

I tried :

`dojo.disconnect(handle) // but I dont have an handle to event`

How to get the handle or is there any better way to to it?

Comment: You must save the handle when you register the event

Comment: I can but I dont want to. any other thoughts. and yes I am assigning inline event using dojo.attach...Thanks for quick response @MauricePerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box solution as far as I know of, so you would have to implement one by yourself. However, this could be a dangerous feature, if you suddenly disconnect all event handlers of a specific type.

However, you could use the `dojo/aspect` module to intercept calls to the `dojo/on` module, for example:

```js
aspect.around(arguments, 0, function(original) {
    on.signals = [ ];
    return function(dom, name, handler) {
        console.log(arguments);
        on.signals.push({
            signal: original.apply(this, arguments),
            name: name
        });
    };
}, true);
```

I didn't find a proper way to put an aspect around a function itself, rather than a function wrapped inside an object. So I used a dirty trick and used the `arguments` array and because the `on` module is my first argument, this will put an aspect around the `dojo/on` reference.

What happens is that when you bind an event handler using `dojo/on`, it will save it inside an array. Now you could write your own `dojo/on::off()` function, for example:

```js
on.off = function(eventName) {
    arrayUtils.forEach(on.signals, function(signal) {
        if (signal.name === eventName) {
             signal.signal.remove();   
        }
    });
};
```

Now you can use:

```js
on.off("click");
```

To disconnect all click event handlers.

A full example can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lj5yG/ but this could probably be improved.

Comment: Great Master. I was waiting for your response

Comment: No problem, whas there a reason why you removed the `dojox/dtl` question from earlier? I noticed that it was suddenly removed. ^^

Comment: I suddenly got the ans while walking through docs. Sorry about that.